# How can I access to a member of a subclass in my view in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview

My goal is to update in the `UIViewController` the label's `text` property of a xib file. The label is declared in the `UIView` subclass with a `IBOutlet` connection.

```
let myView = myClass()
myView.myLabel!.text = "Hello!"
```

The label seems to be `nil`. In fact, I get the following runtime error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. If I don't unwrap the optional, the program runs but the label doesn't update its `text`. 
How can I avoid my app to mark the label as `nil?`

**Bottom line**: If I am understanding it correctly I have to declare two `UIViews` in my `UIViewController`. One loads the nib, the other just updates the label. But they all operate on the very same xib file. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Are you calling this after `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @Andy, correct. I also tried to make the `myView` variable global, and then change the label in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: So `myClass` is a UIView subclass, right? Is `myLabel` instantiated in the init method of `myClass()` ?

Comment: Yes, `myClass` is the UIView subclass. No, it actually isn't instantiated in the init method. I'll look into this, thanks @Andy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The label is declared in the UIView subclass with a IBOutlet
>   connection.

I believe you are taking about `myClass` here which is a subclass of `UIView`. If you have added this into XIB of your `UIViewController` and connected via `IBOutlet` then you do not need to re-initialize it here `let myView = myClass()`.

By doing this you are creating another object which is not shown on your `UIViewController` so effectively any change in the `UILabel` property of this object won't change your UI.

When you connect an `IBOutlet` correctly, it should show up something like below in your swift class file:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView : myClass?
```

Then in your `viewDidLoad` function you can call `self.myView.myLabel!.text = "Hello!"` to see the change.

**EDIT:** Post OP comments:

To load a `UIView` use following:

```
self. myView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("myXib", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? myView
```

Comment: You cannot create an `IBOutlet` without linking your custom `UIView` in `XIB` file on your `UIViewController`. You have 2 options - 1) Drag and drop a UIView in your `ViewController`'s `XIB` file and change the class as `myView`. Then use it as I mentioned in my post.  2) Directly initialize your custom view in your `ViewController`'s `loadView` function like I mentioned in my edited post. Then add that view as subview of your `UIViewController`'s view.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I did what you said, I declared `var myView: UIView!` globally and then loaded the xib file (I used the code you posted) in `viewDidLoad`. I can't, though, access to the subclass' members: `Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'myLabel'`.

Comment: You should not declare it of type `UIView`. It must be of type of your custom view because `myLabel` is a property on your custom view and not on `UIView` so it should look like `var myView: MyView!`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Fixing it right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that `myLabel` is still `nil` when you attempt to set the text to `"Hello!`. Do some logging to verify this.

`myLabel` is still `nil`  because your `myView` object has not yet loaded its view from the nib. you can probably force this load to occur by adding it as a subview, and then set the text to whatever you like.